# Check one by one if the element on the second lists is bigger on another element on the first lists then subtract

Tags: python, list

I'll do my best to explain my concern.

This problem is a practice activity for me as I learn python.

How could I check one by one if the element of the first lists is bigger than the element on the second lists then subtract?

Example:

```
# inputted values
list1 = [50,40,90,30]
list2 = [40,50,40,20]


# desired output:
output = [10,40,50,10]
```

Comment: Do you actually have any `list`s or just lots of variables? eg: do you have `list1 = [50, 40, 90, 30]` and `list2 = [40, 50, 40, 20]` where all the elements are integers?

Comment: @JonClements hello. I'm sorry 
the list is like what you commented list1 = [50, 40, 90, 30] and list2 = [40, 50, 40, 20] and yes, the data type are all integers.

Comment: @m1ks errr... that you should probably [edit] your question to make that clear... at the moment - you don't show any lists - so it's easy to read it as you don't have lists and you've actually got 12 variables... (of which `list2value1` is repeated 4 times :p)

Comment: @JonClements, done editting. I'm very sorry. I hope you already understand my concern hahahaha

Comment: @m1ks presumably your output should also be a list - so another [edit] to show that would make sense as well :)

Comment: @JonClements done!

Answer (score 3):

You needs some real lists, not just four variables. Then do this.

```
list1=[50,40, 90, 30]
list2=[40, 50, 40, 20]
output=[p1-p2 if p1>p2 else p1 for (p1, p2) in zip(list1, list2)]
print(output) #==> [10, 40, 50, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need to iterate over both lists together and compare each element pairwise, then the output will be element from list1 if it is smaller than the element in list2, or else the output will be the difference of list2's element and list1's element

Two ways to achieve this

1. List-comprehension by simultaneously iterating on both lists

```
list1 = [50,40,90,30]
list2 = [40,50,40,20]

print([list1[idx] if list1[idx] < list2[idx] else list1[idx] - list2[idx] for idx in range(len(list1))])
```

Output is `[10, 40, 50, 10]`

2. List-comprehension by iterating on the iterator created by `zip`ping both lists together

```
list1 = [50,40,90,30]
list2 = [40,50,40,20]

print([item1 if item1 < item2 else item1 - item2 for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2)])
```

Output is `[10, 40, 50, 10]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why we are all answering a new python dev with list comps, I believe that a newly minted dev should first start with an easier syntax, and let them learn about the python features (like list comps) that can improve their code.</rant>
To answer your question,
1. you can iterate multiple lists of the same length using python's built-in `zip` which takes multiple iterables as arguments and returns a tuple with the current element of each iterator at the same index, the function works like this;

```
list1 = [50,40,90,30]
list2 = [40,50,40,20]

for i1, i2 in zip(list1, list2):
    print(i1, i2)

# result
50, 40
40, 50
90, 40
30, 20
```

and then 2. you can start adding your logic at each iteration;

```
# if you want to store the results use the results list.
results = []
list1 = [50,40,90,30]
list2 = [40,50,40,20]

for i1, i2 in zip(list1, list2):
    if i1 > i2:
        result.append(i1 - i2)
        # or if you don't need to store the results, just use...
        print(i1 - i2)
    else:
        result.append(i1)
        # same here...
        print(i1)

# result
10
40
50
10
# results == [10, 40, 50, 10]
```

Comment: You can write FORTRAN code in any language. List comprehensions are so widespread and easy to read that it's doing a disservice to a newcomer not to mention list comprehensions.

Comment: yes I agree that we should tell them what list comps are, but first let them understand in a broken down line-by-line explanation of how their result is being computed.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an overkill to use [numpy](https://www.numpy.org/) but the [syntax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is clear and concise:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a1 = np.array([50, 40, 90, 30])
>>> a2 = np.array([40, 50, 40, 20])
>>> np.where(a1 >= a2, a1 - a2, a1)
array([10, 40, 50, 10])
```